# Read data from other app's memory, is it challenging on a jailbroken device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, monitor

I have a signed app running, the app is displaying some `numbers on main screen`. I want to make a new app that keeps `monitoring` those numbers, and use these numbers do further works.

Is it possible on a `jailbroken` device? if yes, what's the necessary steps?

Comment: There are plenty answer for OS X. Being pretty much the same as iOS you can port the code from there.

Comment: If the signed app is written by someone else, please clarify this.  You might need to reverse engineer the app, write a hook to run a snippet of your code (in the "signed" app) when that app writes those numbers to its UI, and then use some interprocess communication technique to communicate the numbers to your app.  You haven't provided nearly enough information to us to recommend a specific solution.

Comment: @Nate That's the answer that I want, could you provide some hints, such as the tools that I need or articles explain this technique, on iOS of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIPasteboard to share common data between apps. Other methods http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Comment: Thanks, but I have no source code of this app, how can I make it share its data at an unknown memory location?  I thought the answer would be like some functions that are capable of reading other app's memory like reading his own memory, then analyze the memory and find that data. It's kinda like game trainers on Windows, but it doesn't write, it just reads.